# Kendo - Error in Cascade when Reading from localStorage

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have the following Cascade event for my kendo dropDownList:

```
cascade: function (e) {
    if (!_viewModel) {
        return;
    }

    if (e.sender.value() == _.find(_taskTypeData, function (type) { return type.TaskTypeSlug == "delete_request"; }).TaskTypeId) {
        _viewModel.set("AssignedToTypeId", _.find(_taskAssignmentTypesData, function (type) { return type.TaskAssignmentTypeSlug == "centre" }).TaskAssignmentTypeId);
        _viewModel.set("CentreId", _.find(_centresData, function (centre) { return centre.CentreSlug == "national" }).CentreId);
        return;
    }

    _viewModel.set("AssignedToTypeId", _.find(_taskAssignmentTypesData, function (type) { return type.TaskAssignmentTypeSlug == "user" }).TaskAssignmentTypeId);
    _viewModel.set("CentreId", localStorage.CentreId);
}
```

When implementing this, a race condition arises with the following error message:

> Cannot read property 'removeClass' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'removeClass' of undefined

I was able to track down where the error occurs to the last line of code. What is odd is that if I hard code an ID for the value in lieu of `localStorage.CentreId` then the race condition goes away.

What could be causing the race condition when setting a value in my observable to a value stored in localStorage?

Comment: There is no `removeClass` in the code you provided. The error must be somewhere else. Also, based on what you have said about *hard code an ID*, it is probably a selector error. Your selector doesn't returns an element hence you could not be calling `removeClass` in it.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown - I actually just found the solution about 1/2 an hour ago. `localStorage.Centreid` was being stored as a String value when it was converted to JSON and CentreId is obviously a FK integer value.For some reason, implicitly converting the String to an Integer failed sometimes, so the solution was to call parseInt on the localStorage value beforehand.